# Base topology of $X\times \mathbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology

**Exercise:**

> Let $(X,t)$ be a topological space where $X=\{1,2\}$ and $t=\{\emptyset , X,\{1\}\}$
> find base of the topology product $X \times \mathbb R^2$

**my solution:**

a base for $t$ is the set $\{X,\{1\}\}$ and for the standard topology of $\mathbb R^2$ is the set $b=\{S(x,r):x\in \mathbb R^2,r>0\}$

So a base topology would be $\{\{(1,S(x,r)),(2,S(x,r))\}, \{(1,S(x,r))\}\}$ **?**

Is this correct?

Comment: No, is $\{X \times S(x,r) : x\in \mathbb R^2, \,r>0\} \cup \{\{1\} \times S(x,r) : x\in \mathbb R^2, \,r>0\}$.

Comment: I assume $R$ is the real numbers?

Comment: $\{2\}\times S$ is not in the product topology, because $\{2\}\notin t.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes $R$ i mean the real numbers, but $X$ is which includes $\{2\}$ i did $ X\times S(x,r)=\{(1,S(x,r)),(2,S(x,r))\}$ is this wrong ?

Comment: Well, your notation $(2,S(x,r))$ is abuse of notation, but no, $\{2\}\times S(x,r)$ is not open in the product topology.

Comment: so what we mean when we write $X \times S(x,r)$ ?

Comment: When you write $X\times S(x,r)$ you mean $\{1,2\}\times S(r,x).$ This set is open in the product topology. $\{2\}\times S(x,r)$ is not.

Comment: ok i get it  now , i was confused because when we write $X\times \{1\}$ we can write it as $\{(1,1), (2,1)\}$

Comment: @PetrosK $X \times S(x,r) = \{(u,y) : u \in X,\, y \in S(x,r)\} = \{(1,y) : y \in S(x,r)\} \cup \{(2,y) : y \in S(x,r)\}$. And, to your last comment: note that the second coordinate of each pair is $1$, not $\{1\}$; so writting things like $(1,S(x,r)), (2,S(x,r))$ is wrong.

Comment: "So a base topology would be..." what do you mean by "base topology"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base for the product is thus given by $\{\{1\} \times S(x,r): x \in X, r>0\} \cup \{\{1,2\} \times S(x,r): x \in X, r>0\}$.

$(1, S(x,r))$ is not correct, that is a single pair (with a *subset*, not an element of $\Bbb R^2$ as the second component, while $\{1\} \times S(x,r)$  is the set of pairs $\{ (1,y) \in X \times \Bbb R^2: d(x,y)<r\}$. Be more careful in the notation of product sets.
The set $\{1,2\} \times S(x,r)$ is all pairs $((i,y): i \in X, d(x,y) < r\}$, so a doubling of the ball, as it were.